# Signing into a website with a link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I'm looking to sign into various social media sites with links. I already have the usernames & passwords available, and I can pass them into any sort of structure I like with the system I use. My basic question is: Is there anyway to take this data, and open a new tab/page, populate the fields and login with web technologies, or should I be looking to build a Chrome Plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on whether a Chrome plugin is what you want.

Comment: If the sites support OpenID try http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml

Comment: @Whymarrh Would a Chrome plugin be able to handle that function?

Comment: @elclanrs Didn't even consider OpenID...Checking it out now! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you have usernames and passwords, you can login to sites via a Chrome plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To log in via link the social network / webmaster must provide such features, but for security reasons most sites does not have such features. There are many Plugins/Addons (some of them even for multiple browsers/platforms.

I use LastPass to store my passwords and auto-logon on websites. LastPass is available for many platforms and free (without smartphone/mobile access).